# How To Call Javascript Function From Another File in EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have a question regarding EJS and how to call a javascript function from another file.

Let's say i have a button,

```
<button onclick="click()">Click Me</button>
```

and the `click()` function is from another file called `click.js`, how do i call it ? because using standard  method doesn't work. 
thanks

Comment: Isn't ejs a template language variant using JavaScript?

Comment: yes, but i have trouble to call a javascript function from another javascript file. got an idea ?

Comment: What has this got to do with ejs? EJS never runs in the browser... --- To run something from "another js file", include the JS file in the HTML using a `script` element.

Comment: I am using ejs as templating engine for express js, and the script tag way doesn't work

Comment: _"script tag way doesn't work"_ - what does this mean? Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve and what is "not working"?

Comment: When it is a normal html adding the file path by the script tag will do the trick, and when using ejs, the function wont be called using the same method. Is it answer your question ?

Comment: If the JS is going to be used by the client, why would you want to run it in EJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click.ejs

```
    <body>
    ...
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="topMenu-hamburguer" onclick="click()">&#9776;</a>

    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/click.js"></script>
    </body>
```

click.js

```
function click() {
    console.log(`Click!`);
}
```

and make sure you have something like this in your app.js, if you dont, just change your path.

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  sourceMap: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```